# Redshift - Killing the application that initiated the Redshift query does not kill it

Tags: java, amazon-redshift

I have a java application which is executing a Redshift COPY command. The application isn't written as a service and so I forcefully kill the process in order to stop it. The java application is killed immediately, however even though the Redshift COPY command is still in progress when the java app is killed, it continues to run on Redshift and successfully completes.

This wasn't the behavior I was expecting. I was expecting that once the connection to Redshift was terminated, the COPY command would terminate with it and the COPY command would rollback.

Is there some setting I need to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a distributed system and a client-server application for this matter is considered distributed system, you usually don't rely on constant communication between the nodes. If you kill your JDBC client on one side, the server is not canceling automatically your SQL query, as it can't know if you killed your query generator, or you just have some network disruption. It would be very annoying if every time you a short network hiccup, you will have to run your COPY command again, which can take a few minutes/hours in some cases.

The "right" way to cancel your query, is to [CANCEL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CANCEL.html) your query.

Comment: Is the CANCEL query only intended to be used manually? Or is there a way to have it hooked up with an application's kill signal? It seems like the query's process id is needed for CANCEL, which is only obtainable through the stv_recents table?

Comment: You can also find the pid (and the option to cancel) from the web console. This is a simple SQL command that you have to send through some connection. This is why I find it hard to attached to a kill signal.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to hook it up with the kill signal but I guess my only option is to wait until the COPY command has completed before allowing my app to shut down. Thanks